# How can I have a QR code that can open the iOS / Android stores across China and South East Asia?

Tags: android, ios, qr-code, great-firewall-of-china

We are developing an app that will be released across south east asia and China.

It is for a product that will have a QR code printed on the packaging, once scanned the QR code will open the relevant app store to download the app.

The problem is in China there are multiple device android stores - google play is blocked by the chinese firewall.

How can we have one QR code that can work in multiple countries and open the correct app store?

Thanks, help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

A QR code is a fixed piece of data. It will point at a URL (though other types of data can be represented), and once printed (in your example) it cannot be changed unless a new packaging design is released. For example, this QR code will always point to https://www.stackoverflow.com

[image: QR Code pointing to StackOverflow.com]

Therefore the QR code alone cannot dynamically point to different app stores based on a user's location. What you will instead need to do is have a hosted script or web page that will geolocate a user via their IP address and redirect them to a particular app store based on their location. However you create this script is up to you, but your printed code will need to point to the public web address of this script.

There's the usual caveats to keep in mind though, a geolocated IP can only give a rough indication as to a user's location, and could be entirely incorrect if the user is using a VPN, for example.

Comment: Could the users Locale (en_US, de_DE, etc)  be a good datapoint to choose which app store to go to? https://gist.github.com/jacobbubu/1836273

Comment: @JoelEsli If the redirect script is able to discern that purely from the browser's user agent, I don't see why not. I can't say for sure though.

Comment: After doing some research, the locale is not a required part of the [browser's user agent](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/user-agent) and the [official specification](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-5.5.3) also doesn't list it.